# Conditional types issue in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

This is a simplified example of a complex code:

```js
type ValueType<T> = [T] extends [string] ? Value<string> : Value<T>;

interface Value<T> {
    set(v: T): void
}

export type Bar<T> = T extends true ? boolean : number

function foo<T>(vt: ValueType<Bar<T>>, v: Bar<T>) {
    vt.set(v); <-- error here
}
```

The latest TypeScript (v4.1.3) fails on the statement `vt.set(v)` with:

> Argument of type 'Bar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & Bar'.

([TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QCrggHlQPigXigG1UBdKCAD2AgDsATAZ2MeACcBLWgc3IH5YiFJlaceeAFyDkWXAG4AsAChlXGmwBmcAMbR4M7HgDeyqGaiMIwABQA3KagCUU2wHsO9ZQF9lyqmFc2YChQSCgAITg2QwIoVApqOiYQthQoAQAjV1cECDhaKClaJABbDIg2XyUNJFptYA5XAo1swztgKX0UdEhMSOjcHAAaKHsIqMNHKBMlc1HgADpLG1tHRSUvIA))

Is this behavior documented somewhere or is it a bug?

Comment: Your `Bar` and `ValueType` aliases are superfluous here. Could you provide an example where [removing them would _not_ be trivial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcIB4AqAfMgN4CwAUMtcgM4RgAUAbgFzL4CU7zA9sABNKAX0qUYWEAjDBeIZDF68ChFmHbpseIgBpkbDp1KUa+sADp6TZpwDcIoA)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Not sure what you mean. Your example does not fail. My fails. So you example is different.

Comment: "your example" (typo cannot be fixed after 5 mins)

Answer (score 1):

## What is the error

Here is the error you are getting:

```
Argument of type 'Bar<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & Bar<T>'. 
  Type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string & Bar<T>'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string & Bar<T>'. 
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. 
       Type 'Bar<T>' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

So the root cause is `Type 'Bar<T>' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.` and it makes perfect sense to have this error and we explain this below

## Explanation

### Fact 1:

Based on `export type Bar<T> = T extends true ? boolean : number`

- Bar can only be `boolean` or `number`

### Fact 2:

Based on `type ValueType<T> = [T] extends [string] ? Value<string> : Value<T>;`

- Means that `ValueType` can be `Value<string>`

### Fact 3:

Based on `foo<T>(vt: ValueType<Bar<T>>, v: Bar<T>)`

- Using Fact 2, means that `means vt.set can take string`

### Resolution

Based on Fact 1 (can only be `boolean` or `number`) and Fact 2 (can take a `string`) we have the error message from TypeScript: `Type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Comment: I do not understand why `vt.set` can take `string`. As `Bar<T>` can only be `boolean` or `number`. Therefore `[number | boolean] extends [string]` is false.